# Separate Class for OkHttp Requests

Tags: android, asynchronous, okhttp, apprequests

I use OkHttp for requests to my raspberry. I am thinking about putting the requests in a separate class.

Currently I have one method to send requests. The code is as follows:

```
private void sendRequest(String url, JSONObject json) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendRequest: Das Json: " + json);
        // Authentication for the request to raspberry
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                String credential = Credentials.basic("username", "password");
                return response.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", credential)
                        .build();
            }
        });

        // Sending out the request to the raspberry
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = client.build();

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[]{});
        if( json != null) {
            body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(
                    "application/json"),
                    json.toString()
            );
        }

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.d(LOG, "Big Fail");

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
                    if( !response.isSuccessful() ) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: We are in !response.successful()");
                        throw new IOException("Response not successful: " + response );
                    }
                    Log.d(LOG, "onResponse: Response is: " + responseBody.string());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(LOG, "onResponse: failed!" + e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is an example how the sendRequest() function is called:

```
private void makePremixCall(Premix premix) {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        ArrayList<Premixable> usedPremixables = premix.getUsedPremixables();
        for(Premixable usedPremixable: usedPremixables) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("Silo", usedPremixable.getmSilo());
                jsonObject.put("Gramm", usedPremixable.getmKgPerCow() * mFeeding.getmNumberOfCows());
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("Components", jsonArray);
            sendRequest("http://192.168.178.49:5000/evaluatePost", jsonObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "makePremixCall: " + e);
        }
    }
```

My problem with this: I would like to have a separate class, which offers the function makePremix(Premix premix) and other functions that I need.

The only solution that comes to my mind is implementing the requests synchronously in the separate class and call that separate class in an AsyncTask in the class I am working in.

Do I oversee something? Is there a way to create a separate class and still use the OkHttp enqueue method?

Comment: Could you please show some code

Comment: Here you go, I added the code of the relevant functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract `makePremix(Premix premix)` in a separate class and make `sendRequest()` public (or maybe package-private depending on your use case).

```
public void sendRequest(String url, JSONObject json)
```

However since `sendRequest` is generic and can be used by any other `makeAnotherCall()` in some other class you would need to get back result of every requests. Hence you can extract the Callback out of `sendRequest()`

```
public void sendRequest(String url, JSONObject json, Callback callback)
```

Now your `sendRequest` will look like

```
private void sendRequest(String url, JSONObject json) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sendRequest: Das Json: " + json);
        // Authentication for the request to raspberry
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.authenticator(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                String credential = Credentials.basic("username", "password");
                return response.request().newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", credential)
                        .build();
            }
        });

        // Sending out the request to the raspberry
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = client.build();

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(null, new byte[]{});
        if( json != null) {
            body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(
                    "application/json"),
                    json.toString()
            );
        }

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body)
                .build();

        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }
```

Hope it makes sense!

Also as a side note, see  that you are creating a new OkHttp Client every time you call `sendRequest`. You could probably optimise memory here by caching the client and reusing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This makes sense to me. However,  I was actually hoping for a solution allowing me to also put the sendRequest() method into the separate class.

Comment: I dont follow sendRequest and makePremix can now be in separate classes.

Comment: Have a class say `HttpManager` which keeps a okhttp client and exposes `sendRequest`. And from another class, say `PremixRepository` (which would have `makePremise` call `sendRequest`

Comment: Sorry, I might have explained this wrong. I want to have makePremix() and sendRequest() in one class, but separate from the rest of the code.
Let's both methods are in class HttpManager, now in my other classes I want to be able to do something like HttpManager.makePremix(premix1)

Comment: Just take the callback as a parameter. `HttpManager.makePremise(premix, callback)`. This will let HttpManager take care of the threading logic.